# Log incoming and outgoing connections on my Leased Line

Tags: networking, network-monitoring, security

I am a System Administrator at a college where we have a leased line internet connectivity and 32 Static IPs. The Local; network is running behind the Juniper Firewall. Now I would like to log all the incoming and outgoing traffic / Connections on my internet. (Incoming means the who ever access the site hosted in my Static IPs and i mean the outgoing as the connection that are browsed on my internet connection). Through Squid / TMG i am able to get only the outgoing logs. In Juniper firewall i am able to  get only the same day's report.

Is there any possibility of getting reports for more than one day like one week / month overall / Single Local IP.

Just give me a basic way to go about.

Thanks

Comment: What Juniper Model? Can the Juniper log to a syslog server?

Comment: My firewall model is juniper ssg 140, and it supports System logs.@chewbakka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I second the syslog suggestion. Most firewall appliances support it. If you've got any Linux or Unix machines on your network, a syslog receiver is probably already available to you. If you want to log on Windows, have a look at the free Kiwi Syslog products. http://www.kiwisyslog.com/

Comment: Kiwi syslog is a commercial software...is there any free  /opensource alternatives..@msinatl

Answer (score 2):

The SSG 140 doesn't support "J Flow" (Juniper's Netflow-alike protocol) and using SYSLOG means having to create rules to match the traffic you're looking for to create SYSLOG events (if I understand what I'm reading about this device). I think I'd throw up a SPAN port on your switch and use something like [nprobe](http://www.ntop.org/products/nprobe/) to gather Netflow data, personally.